# HackerRank closest number

Tags: java

Given a list of unsorted integers, find the pair of elements that have the smallest absolute difference between them. If there are multiple pairs, find them all.

My reasoning was to compare each: `arr[j] - arr[i]` with `lowest` and if it is smaller or equal to that, add that value to the array lowest, but it's not working.

Code:

```java
static int[] closestNumbers(int[] arr) {
    int lowest = arr[1] - arr[0];
    int lowestArray[] = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i]) < lowest) {
                lowest = Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == lowest) {
            lowestArray[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return lowestArray;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "its not working"

Comment: You appear to be recording what the lowest difference from any starting point was, rather than what the actual pairs with the least gap

Comment: Once you sort the array, any difference arr[j]-arr[i] will always be greater than or equal to zero if j>i ... so you don't need to do Math.abs everytime

Comment: You started good with sorting. The idea is to keep track of Pairs (so, elements at indices 0 and 1 is first pair, elements at indices 1 and 2 are second pair etc) and to keep only Pairs with absolute difference which is greater then the previous maximal one. For the complete solution you can take a look at https://github.com/TheJavaGuy/HackerRankSolutions/blob/master/src/main/java/org/thejavaguy/hackerrank/sorting/easy/ClosestNumbers.java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [integers which have smallest absolute difference there can be one such pair or multiple such pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189282/integers-which-have-smallest-absolute-difference-there-can-be-one-such-pair-or-m)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you initialize your lowest array like this,

```
int[] lowest = new int[arr.length];
```

you are actually initializing it with zeros. Also, whenever you are taking arr[j]-arr[i], it will always be greater than or equal to zero (since your array is sorted in an ascending fashion), leading to incorrect results because the following if statement,

```
if(Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i]) <= lowest[l]) {
     lowest[l] = Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i]);
}
```

will never execute for differences greater than 0.

Initialize the lowest array like so,

```
for(int i=0;i<lowest.length;i++){ 
    lowest[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
}
```

Also, your outer loop for the i variable starts with i=1, but it should start with i=0

Comment: Initialize each array element with Integer.MAX_VALUE, like so, for(int i=0;i<lowest.length;i++){
            lowest[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } ... since your array is sorted initially, arr[j]>=arr[i] for all j>=i, right? This means that arr[j] - arr[i]>=0 for all j>=i

Comment: But by saying lowest[l] = Integer.MAX_VALUE, the condition if arr[j]  - arr[i] will never become true.

Comment: @LolLol, why won't it happen? Once you find that arr[j] - arr[i] <= lowest[l], you will update the lowest[l] value

Comment: @LolLol, consider this example, arr = {-5, 1, 1000} ... max difference is 1000-(-5) = 1005 which is less than Integer.MAX_VALUE (i.e 2,147,483,647) so your if condition will always execute the first time, but subsequently when you update lowest array, it will not hold 2,147,483,647 in that particular position, it will be 1005 or whatever arr[j]-arr[i] gives

Comment: True, sorry, I was reasoning poorly, thinking for all arr[j] - arr[i] > Integer.MAX_VALUE, therefore it would never execute.

Comment: But that still wouldn't fix my code, as it would (for as long as arr[j] - arr[i] < Integer.MAX_VALUE), always be true. Therfore it wouldn't let me find the minimum value.

Comment: @LolLol, I am not saying that you should write the condition as arr[j] - arr[i] < Integer.MAX_VALUE ... leave it as you have written it right now, like arr[j] - arr[i] < lowest[l] ... the only thing is that initially, lowest[l] will be equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE and then when arr[j] - arr[i] < lowest[l] becomes true, lowest[l] will now become arr[j]-arr[i] ... so the next time for some new i,j, you are going to compare with new lowest[l] and not Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: I understood that, I was just saying since lowest[l] = Integer.MAX_VALUE, comparing it to integer.MAX_VALUE or to lowest[l] is the same thing, it will return true.

I edited my code to what I think is something that's really close to the solution. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the required code:-

```
import java.util.*; 

class GFG 
{ 

// Returns minimum difference between 
// any two pair in arr[0..n-1] 
static void printMinDiffPairs(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    if (n <= 1) 
    return; 

    // Sort array elements 
    Arrays.sort(arr); 

    // Compare differences of adjacent 
    // pairs to find the minimum difference. 
    int minDiff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) 
    minDiff = Math.min(minDiff, arr[i] - arr[i-1]); 

    // Traverse array again and print all pairs 
    // with difference as minDiff. 
    for ( int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        if ((arr[i] - arr[i-1]) == minDiff) 
        { 
        System.out.print("(" + arr[i-1] + ", "
                        + arr[i] + ")," ); 
        }                    
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void main (String[] args) 
{ 
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 2, 4, 1}; 
    int n = arr.length; 
    printMinDiffPairs(arr, n); 
} 
}
```

**Does above program handle duplicates?**

The cases like {x, x, x} are not handled by above program. For this case, the expected output (x, x), (x, x), (x, x), but above program prints (x, x), (x, x)

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] closestNumbers(int[] arr) {
        int minAbs = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int[] out = new int[(arr.length) + 3];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            minAbs = Math.min(minAbs, Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i - 1]));
            
        }
        
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(minAbs ==Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i - 1])) {
                out[j++]=arr[i - 1];
                out[j++]=arr[i];
            }
        }
        int[] tem= new int[j];
        for(int i=0; i<j;i++) {
            tem[i]=out[i];
        }
        
        
        return tem;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.